# OctoberCMS translation language change error using ajax

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

First install [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/) using composer and git and then install [translate](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-translate) plugin with two language English and Spanish. But I have an error with the localePicker. When I choose a language, I get the following error;

```
AJAX handler 'onSwitchLocale' was not found.
```

[image]

According to this thread, is a October related issue. But I just want to be sure, how can I resolve it?

Please note that mysite.com/{langcode}/ works.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The AJAX handler onswitchlocale was not found simply means you did not attach the component of RainLab.Translate to your page or layout

Add to your layout :

```
[localePicker]
forceUrl = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a 2021 update: the Ajax handler will be added automatically if you add the Locale Picker component to your **layout**, **not** partials or page, if the latter are based on a layout. This point is important. See screenshot.

Inside of **page** that invokes the layout, my HTML implementation is:

```
 {% if activeLocale == 'en' %}<a href="#" data-request="onSwitchLocale" data-request-data="locale: 'fr'"><img src="flgfr.png" title="Version française" /></a>{% endif %}
 {% if activeLocale == 'fr' %}<a href="#" data-request="onSwitchLocale" data-request-data="locale: 'en'"><img src="flgen.png" title="English version" /></a>{% endif %}
```

To be noted that clicking the image will only force the URL to /fr or /en if you tick the "force URL schema" option.
[image]

Comment: This is a 2023 update With v3:
The above was valid for v2, but since v3, localePicker component was renamed sitePicker. If you only need a backend business code to run upon locale change, then just use the `data-request` / `data-request-data` HTML attribute. But if you want a simple redirection to `/<lang>`, like `/en` or `/fr`, then remove both extra HTML attrs, and use `<a href="/fr">` and `<a href="/en">`, for example.
BTW, no behaviour change was noted upon setting forceUrl to 1 or 0 with 3.x version...

Comment: If you're using the href method for switching locale, you don't even need to include the `sitePicker` component in your layout.

Comment: The most important point in 3.x, which is NOT documented, is the fact that you SHOULD NOT try to remove the `'en'` locale, i.e; English (US). This is the default locale, 'en' is hard-coded everywhere in OctoberCMS, and if you're trying to remove it and place en-au instead for example, you WILL get an "EN-AU" index not found in array... Took me hours to figure that out.